# how can we get image from local?

Tags: iphone, ios

I store image in local by this code...

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image.png"];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
```

[imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];

I can see this image in my iphone simulator bundle ...but how can i get back this image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean recreate the image from a file, you can do that very simply by using `UIImage`'s [`+imageWithContentsOfFile:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW12) method:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"someImageName"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPathToFile];
```